# Large title to small title switch in navigation bar is not smooth iOS 13, sticky

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a `UINavigationController` with default value of it's `navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true` .

I am switching that to `false` when I `push`  into a new scene lets call it (`DetailsViewController`), by changing it into the `viewWillDisappear` .

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
   navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
}
```

Now in `DetailsViewController` I am using `willMove(to parent:)` .

```
override func willMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
}
```

To transition back to large titles .

Observe the attached snapshots of how **iOS 13** doing it with how **iOS 12** is doing it, considering **iOS 12** is the correct behavior.

**iOS 13** :

[image: iOS 13]

**iOS 12** :

[image: iOS 12]

Comment: You don't have to change `.prefersLargeTitles` at all when pushing a detail view controller to the navigation stack, it will automatically use a small title and then go back to the large one once you get back to the root view controller, as far as I know

Comment: @henrik-dmg I'am not sure if it was like that before, but not anymore everything goes to large title if i did so, i have tried that .

Comment: `largeTitleDisplayMode` to .`automatic` and you should get the desired transition.

Comment: @HarryJ where  ?

Comment: Within your viewDidLoad or navigation controller, `navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic`

Comment: yeah, tried that not working .

Comment: Have to try to play with dispatch after for put some delay, it looks like animation when pop VC speed in ios13 creating issue.

Comment: @guru i am not sure that would solve it but ill give it a try .

Answer (score 94, accepted):

What you're doing was always wrong. You should set `prefersLargeTitles` to `true` once for the navigation bar and never touch it again.

The way to change what each view controller does about large titles as it appears is that that view controller sets its own `navigationItem` (in its `viewDidLoad`) to have the desired `largeTitleDisplayMode`. So if the first v.c. has `.always` and the second has `.never` everything will be smooth.

Comment: Such a good answer! Never knew that was the way to have large and small titles at the same time!

Comment: Just make sure to call `self.navigationItem` and not `self.navigationController.navigationItem`

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5, Xcode 13:**

UIViewController(1) + UINavigationController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    navigationItem.title = "Your title here"
}
```

UIViewController(2 - "i.e.: detailsViewController"):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
    navigationItem.title = "Your title here"
}
```

It works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and had to place a NavigationItem on the second ViewController's storyboard. My NavigationItem was being created automatically by the segue and its `prefersLargeTitle` in the `viewDidLoad()` was not finished creating before the view appeared. Adding a NavigationItem to the storyboard fixed this issue and allowed me to set the `prefersLargeTitle` in the storyboard's properties menu.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this problem was occurring during a segue to a view controller which is a child of a `UITabBarController`. Setting `largeTitleDisplayMode` on the child view controller was not enough to fix this bug.

I have solved the issue by adding a navigation item to the UITabBarController scene and setting `largeTitleDisplayMode` as `.never` there.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem like this:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    title = ""
}
```

All ingenious is simple))

Comment: What will happen if i swapped the second VC slowly with my finger ? and observe the title meanwhile

Comment: It is understood that the transition is organized by a button and it will not be possible to slow down this process with a finger. The title is restored in a different life cycle of the application.

Comment: https://gfycat.com/considerateunimportantgecko - GIF

Answer (score 0):

```
final class CustomHosting<Content: View>: UIHostingController<Content> {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
    }
}
```

I fixed same problem like this :) My problem is presenting SUI Detail Collection view from UIKit Collection, and had some jumping while navigation title changing.

Answer (score 0):

**iOS Large Title**

- call `prefersLargeTitles = true` only once for NavigavionViewController
- regulate the size by `largeTitleDisplayMode`

First ViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.title = "My Title 1"
    
    //1
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

    //2
    self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
}
```

Second ViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.title = "My Title 2"

    //2
    self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
}
```

Looks like:

[image]

**Some notes**

Also take into account that if you set custom leftBarButtonItem image for the second ViewController the transition animation will be different

```
let backButtonImage = self.image
let backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: backButtonImage, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(backClicked))
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem
```

Looks like:

[image]