# Swift How can I keep only the first page with a large title?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem, viewdidload

The large title of navigation item comes out when the app just describes execution. However, when I move to another page and come back, that mode is turned off. Create a viewDidLoad for each page as follows: What's the problem?

```
class CollectionViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
}
```

next page

```
class AssetCollectionViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
}
```

Possibly adding code didn't work.

```
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    
    self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
}
```

Comment: [Similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58300644/large-title-to-small-title-switch-in-navigation-bar-is-not-smooth-ios-13-sticky)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about doing all the implementation in your CollectionViewController like so:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
}
```

As apple says about `viewDidLoad`:

> This method is called after the view controller has loaded its view
> hierarchy into memory

you should rather use `viewWillAppear`:

> This method is called before the view controller's view is about to be
> added to a view hierarchy and before any animations are configured for
> showing the view. You can override this method to perform custom tasks
> associated with displaying the view. For example, you might use this
> method to change the orientation or style of the status bar to
> coordinate with the orientation or style of the view being presented.
> If you override this method, you must call super at some point in your
> implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Change titleDisplay mode in **viewWillppear** function as it will always execute

```
class CollectionViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)    
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this doesn't work. It seems to be a very strange problem.....

Answer (score 0):

When you're setting `navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode` in `viewDidDisappear(_:)`, you're doing it for the current controller's `navigationItem`.

I suggest you to create `UINavigationController` subclass with:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
}
```

Then set `navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode` to `.never` in controllers, where you don't want large title.